# How to Play the Audio Files on ListView Item Click instead of clicking on Play Button?

Tags: android

[image: Images]

I am using this Library:

```
implementation 'com.github.jeancsanchez:JcPlayer:2.6.16'
```

I got success in playing audio files from /res/raw folder.

> Now, How can I play the Audio clicking on ListView Items ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    jcPlayerView = (JcPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.jcplayer);

    list_view = findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    dataList.add("Java");
    dataList.add("Android");
    dataList.add("JavaEE");
    dataList.add("JSP");
    dataList.add("JDBC");
    dataList.add("JSP");
    dataList.add("JDBC");
    dataList.add("JSP");
    dataList.add("JDBC");
    dataList.add("JSP");
    dataList.add("JDBC");
    dataList.add("JSP");
    dataList.add("JDBC");
    dataList.add("JSP");
    dataList.add("JDBC");

    final ArrayList<JcAudio> jcAudios = new ArrayList<>();
    jcAudios.add(JcAudio.createFromRaw("Sample file", R.raw.musicfile));
    jcAudios.add(JcAudio.createFromRaw("Pyar Toh Tha", R.raw.pyartohtha));
    jcPlayerView.initPlaylist(jcAudios, null);



    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String z =(String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text here is " +  z, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

I wonder if it is possible if I click on an Item in the `ListView`

Comment: I didn't get your question what specifically you wanted ?

Comment: I mean when I click an Item on a ListView, the Song starts to Play instead of clicking in the Play Button as shown in above Image @Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

it is awesome but it required full explanation such as XML design view and full correct code

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33015220)

Comment: could you tell me how I can play audio from a URL using your solution?